# Overriding `equals()` method gives unexpected result in `HashMap`

Tags: java, scjp

It is question from OCJP 6 exam, so it is intentionally not fully correct (but legal).

Given code:

```
class ToDos {
    String day;

    public ToDos(String d) {
        day = d;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((ToDos) o).day == day;
    }

    public int hashCode() { return 9; }
}

public class MapEQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<ToDos, String> map = new HashMap<ToDos, String>();

        ToDos t1 = new ToDos("Monday");
        ToDos t2 = new ToDos("Mond" + "a" + "y");
        ToDos t3 = new ToDos("Tuesday");

        map.put(t1, "a");
        map.put(t2, "b");
        map.put(t3, "c");

        System.out.println(map.size());
    }

}
```

Why output is 2? I mean, `equals` method is not overriden corretcly, so `t1.day == t2.day` supposed to be false! Am I'm missed something?

Comment: You should try to see the IL code. It is possible that Java compiler has optimize and intern that Monday string.

Comment: It is question from SCJP 6 (now OCJP 6) exam :)

Comment: That mean you should study more. To understand why this is happening.

Comment: @Vash that means that this class is intentionally not appropriate.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, beside that was na example hashcode(), your link is invalid..

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev, You have written that in the question ;-).

Comment: @Vash: thanks, I can't edit that comment, so deleting and reposting fixed: BTW not only `equals()` but your `hashCode()` method is also not the best one can imagine. Consider [`42`](http://bit.ly/bhllCV) instead ;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because:

```
"Mond" + "a" + "y"
```

is evaluated at compile time to "Monday" thus resulting in just one instance in string pool. There is a much simpler test to examine this behavior:

```
System.out.println("Mond" + "a" + "y" == "Monday");  //true

String y = "y";
System.out.println("Mond" + "a" + y == "Monday");  //false

final String y2 = "y";
System.out.println("Mond" + "a" + y2 == "Monday");  //true
```

Examples above should give you some overview on how the compiler treats string concatenation.

And to be on the safe side, always use:

```
return ((ToDos) o).day.equals(day);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to previous answers ... another example illustrating the point:

```
String a = "Monday";
String b = new String("Monday");
String c = "Monday";

(a == b)      // false
(a.equals(b)) // true

(a == c)      // true
(a.equals(c)) // true
```

Both `a` and `c` point to the same object in the String pool.